# PHP and MySQL - What gets stored in the variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables

What gets stored in the first $products variable? I'm new to using the debugger and am getting the actual query stored there, is that right?

```
$products = "SELECT * FROM product"??

function getProduct() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
    try {
        global $db;
        $products = $db->query($query); // this line
        $products = $products->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($products);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
    }
}
```

Comment: [PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: ^ The manual at php.net has parameters, return values, and examples for nearly every function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a PDO Instance of your query. If it succeeds. If not it is a boolean of false.

[PDO Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)